# Automate inserting OLE into Autocad drawings using web based programming language

Tags: c#, php, python, autocad

I am trying to insert and Excel object into and Autocad file (DWG), I need to do this by running some sort of script that will open the DWG file, import he Excel Sheet and then save the DWG file.

I need to do this using a web based programming language eg PHP, C#, Python etc.

If anyone could please point me in the right direction or even confirm that this can be done that would be a great help.

Answer (score 0):

Similar question here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/23471957/474702

It is not advisable to run instances of applications that expect direct user interaction from web based software, particularly if you expect the AutoCAD interop to be hosted on the server.

You may have to use a windows form or WPF application to work with AutoCAD. With this option, you can use C# or visual basic.Net. I have worked extensively with the AutoCAD interop for creating drawings, complete with BOMs.

AutoCAD.Application interop may not allow for non-visual interaction.